# X server. How to know the screen number application was connected to?

Tags: x11

Is it possible to know the X11 screen number the application was connected to?
I know that if `NULL` is passed to `XOpenDisplay`, one can obtain the default screen number. But if application was connected to some display with some screen number, how to obtain the number?

For now I parse the display connection string to obtain the screen number. Maybe there are a function for that?